# C++ to C# Translator

Tags: c++, code-translation

i found a translator for c++ to c# , but it doesn't work. (Code2Code.net)

Test with cout

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
cout << "Hello World";
return 0;
}
```

The Results becomes

```
public static int Main(string [] argv) 
{ 
cout << "Hello World"; 
return 0; 
}
```

My Question to you, is = is it any other translator that works for C++ to C# (dont need to be free)

Comment: That website barely even functions correctly.

Comment: If you don't need it to be free, hire a programmer to do it. ;)

Answer (score 7):

I am not aware of any as this kind of translation would be *very* difficult to do.  You are trying to translate code that was written in an unmanaged language into a language that is managed.  Even if you were able to translate the code you would have almost every method marked as `unsafe` which would negate most of the benefits of moving to C# in the first place.

This seems like a bad idea - you ought to be thinking about rewriting the application from scratch.

Comment: My experience tells me that any implementation of a software solution will be has to be intimately tied to the programming language's platform => if not "transforming" the C++ code into C++/CLI (like they did with Quake 2) it has to be re-implemented, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

My suggestions would be to initially use C++/CLI to port over the C++ code to a managed environment. Once working in the managed world, build new code in C# around it. If there are key areas of the existing code that are actively changing, consider porting to C# at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any translation engine for C++ -> C# could do more than safe a bit of typing on boilerplate code (fix basic syntax) - as the frameworks used in C++ and C# are fundamentally different, and you will run into problems as soon as the translator has to deal with pointers arithmetics and stuff like this.

Given the complex syntax of C++ and the crazy stuff you can do with it (think [Boost](http://www.boost.org)) I guess any translator would run into serious trouble sooner or later. See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2005/02/28/382083.aspx) for some alternative suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Code2Code.net explicitly states

> You accept that this page does only half the work.
>
> ...
>
> In most cases, the translated code will not even compile.